# why value inside retrofit response differ from value outside?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I saw many many stackoverflow about the same question but I still stuck in my circle.

I'm trying to return a user token from API. The response is success and I can LOG it. but I can't return it because the function will return before the enqueue completed (this is what I think)

Please see the code below:

```
fun login(username: String, password: String): Result<LoggedInUser> {

        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https:api/customers/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()
        val userApi= retrofit.create<UserApiKotlin>()
        var  pass: String ="SecYourPa$$"
        val r= UserRequestModel("coding", pass)
        var fakeUser = LoggedInUser(
            java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "Jane Doe",
            "gfgfgfgf", "trtrtr", "trtrtrtr", "abababababab"
        )
       var sss="1"
        userApi.login(r).enqueue(object : Callback<LoggedInUser> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<LoggedInUser>, response: Response<LoggedInUser>
            ) {
                fakeUser = LoggedInUser(
                    java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "Jane Doe",
                    "gfgfgfgf", "trtrtr", "trtrtrtr", "xcxcxcxc"
                )
                sss = "tttttt"
                fakeUser = response.body()!!
                Log.e("inside Retrofit", sss)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoggedInUser>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("fauluer", "Unable to submit post to API.")
            }
        })


    Log.e("outside retrofit", sss)
    return Result.Success(fakeUser)
}
```

and this the output show that it will show and execute the function (and return the initial value) before api get the value from server

[image]

Comment: Because outsite Log.e("outside retrofit", sss)call first before get your api response.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Answer (score 0):

`userApi.login(r).enqueue` is an asynchronous call which will run on another thread. A network call can take severall milliseconds or seconds so you won't get the result immediately.

The code happens in this order:

1. You call `userApi.login(r).enqueue` -> Network call starts in parallel on another thread
2. You return `Result.Success(fakeUser)`
3. The network call finishes -> Code inside your callback in `onResponse` or `onFailure` is executed

As you see, you are returning a result before the network call even finishes. Your log shows the same.

Comment: You are right. but how to  return the value  came from api? or how make the "return" wait until the value from api arriving?

Comment: You can pass in the callback into the login method externally: `fun login(username: String, password: String, callback: Callback<LoggedInUser>)`. The calling function would then need to implement a callback. `login` doesn't return anything then.